# Counting some data array not work

Tags: mysql, count

dear all.can you tell me how to collecting this data in mysql:

```
item        colour
nut         brown
nut         black
```

i want the result like:

```
item       colour_qty
nut         2
```

and i have try like this, but didn't work:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(colour) AS colour_qty FROM mytable
```

How do i do that?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a group by clause at the end (GROUP BY item) to get the proper results.

```
SELECT item, COUNT(colour) AS colour_qty FROM mytable GROUP BY item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT item, COUNT(colour) AS colour_qty
FROM mytable
GROUP BY item
```